# How to copy files in /Applications/* using Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, applications, copy-paste

```
# whoami
root

# pwd
/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/MacOS

# cp Calendar Calendar.backup
cp: Calendar.backup: Operation not permitted
```

im curious to know why im not able to copy applications from a root terminal using the `cp` command?

```
sh-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType 
Software:
System Software Overview:

  System Version: macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 17.5.0
  Boot Volume: lily
  Boot Mode: Normal
  Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
  User Name: System Administrator (root)
  Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled
  Time since boot: 2:03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications that come preinstalled with macOS are [protected by SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899).  The Calendar App, being preinstalled falls under this category.  Firefox, for example, wouldn't.

So, anything in

- `/Applications/Calendar/.....` is protected
- `/Applications/3rdPartyApp/....` is not

> System Integrity Protection restricts the root user account and limits the actions that the root user can perform on protected parts of the Mac operating system.